# How to find a file(.php) in php project by opening it in browser?

Tags: php

I am working on a web project.Everything is placed inside iframe.After opening project in url, when I click any link or open any page , I have to find location of the opened page in my project directory(i.e.localhost).Anyone have any idea?I tried everything I could but couldn't solve the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking to find the local file path of the file in the PHP code? Btw, why is this tagged with javascript, html and css?

Comment: What you have tried before? show some code and update your question.

Comment: After opening project in url, when I click any link or open any page , I have to find location of the opened page in my project directory(i.e.localhost) .

Comment: Repeating what's already is in the question doesn't clarify things.

Comment: While you develop, why not access the site directly, without the iframe?Then you can see the URL in the browser?

Comment: Example:lets say I have a social network.When I click profile,I need to find that page.Similarly,if I click add_ friend page,I need to find which page contains the code of that page in my computer server.

Comment: Is site built with PHP? Are you using some framework with a router? mod_rewrite? There are too many unknowns to be able to answer your question.

Comment: I tried xdebug to find location....

Comment: yes the site is built in core php.....

Comment: Project uses javascript,html,css so I just listed them....

Comment: Your question is way too broad, since there still are too many unknowns. Regarding your tags, only add tags that's relevant for your actual issue in your question.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like "How do you make a hyperlink?" to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can comminucate with your iframe by *message* event. Just look at [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

1. Your app in iframe have to send information about file, e.g:

   ```
   var message = {type: 'fileInfo', path: yourFilePath}
   window.parent.postMessage(message, targetOrigin);
   ```

   (**yourFilePath** you have to set into JS from your PHP code)
2. Your app in main window can catch this message:

   ```
   window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
       if (event.origin !== YOUR_ORIGIN) return;

       if (event.data.type === 'fileInfo') {
           var filePath = event.data.path;
           //do something
       }
   }, false);
   ```

Comment: I'd advise against trying to answer questions as poor as this one.  It will only encourage more poor questions.

Comment: Hm, but is there any a clear boundary between poor and non-poor questions? I thought I had clearly understood this problem.

P.S. Maybe lazy answerers aren't better than lazy questioners? :)

Comment: The question doesn't describe a specific problem or show any evidence on the part of the poster that they have attempted to figure out a solution.  There's no code, no description of the expected result versus the actual result, etc.

Comment: OK, I've understood your position